# How to place divs under one another while using flex to avoid the extra gap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a webpage where I want the layout to be like the screenshot. Basically, I want the elements to begin under the first element if there is space. I have added the current css and html for the page.

Is it possible? Could someone help, please.
Thanks!

[image]

```css
.main {
    width: 1024px;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container div {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="one"> First element </div>
    <div class="two"> Second element<br />
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
    <div class="three"> Third element </div>
    <div class="forth"> Forth element </div>
    <div class="five"> Five element </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS Flex doesn't have masonry feature yet, so to achieve this you need to create two columns left will have navigations to click and data will be shown in right big container.

Comment: What did you mean by beginning under the first element? Each element below the other?

Comment: I want the content to be in 2 column layout. If there is space after first element (since the second element has too much data), so I want the third element to get placed after first element as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on your screenshot. Essentially you should nest both sides in their own respective divs. Then you can flex the left side and use `flex-direction: column;` with `gap` to space them out. Then you can take your parent `main` which has everything nested inside of it, and use a standard `display: flex;` with that element.

```css
.main {
  width: 1024px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  white-space: nowrap;
  gap: 25px;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.forth {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  margin: 5px;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="one"> First element </div>
      <div class="three"> Third element </div>
      <div class="forth"> Forth element </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="two"> Second element<br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```